# Dolibarr Table Foreign Key Relationship

Tags: phpmyadmin, dolibarr

I just installed Dolibarr by running the code under /htdocs/install/index.php.  The software installed fine.  It is up and running.  I was trying to trace foreign key relationship within a table, specifically llx societe, by using PHPMYADMIN->structure->relation view.  Nothing showed up.  According to documentation, there should be some foreign key restraints on the table.  Could some shed some light on this?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All foreign keys created during Dolibarr installation are defined into files

htdocs/install/mysql/tables/*.key.sql

(Note that even if you use postgresql, declaration file of foreign keys are stored into this path).
If you can't find it in such files, it means it there is no "strict" foreign key. But this does not means that there is no relation with the table.

Note that with Dolibarr v9, there is a graphical description of database structure available in a workbench file in dev/resources/dbmodel (you need to get dolibarr from github to have this directory as it is not provided with common packages).

Answer (score 0):

Go to **htdocs/install/yourdatabase/tables**, and  open file `llx_societe.key.sql`, you will see all foreign key

Comment: Thank you.  I see that some foreign key relations are not enforced.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Heidisql` is [open source](https://www.heidisql.com/)  and you can see the `foreign keys`.
I'm looking at the table categorie_user right now and have `fk_categorie_user_categorie_rowid` and `fk_categorie_user_fk_user`

Good luck